# Чтение байткода, генерируемого интерпретатором PHP

Tags: php, ассемблер, дизассемблирование

Есть ли возможность "влезть" в этап выполнения PHP кода между считыванием высокоуровневого скрипта и компиляцией его в непосредственный ассемблер и посмотреть, какие оп-коды генерируются?

Comment: реальная-то задача какая?

Comment: @Etki, обход bcompile

Comment: ага, а задача-то какая? что сделать-то нужно?

Answer (score 1):

раз тебе оп-коды нужны, смотри сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795425/how-to-get-opcodes-of-php

и вот хорошая ссылка: https://ctors.net/2015/09/11/php_opcodes, говорят, работает с php7 тоже

короче, тебе нужен  Vulcan Logic Disassembler

если бы были нужны байткоды - запустить bcompiler_write_file на нужном файле

Comment: Направление мысли верное, вот только задача диаметрально противоположная - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.bcompiler-write-file.php

Comment: В совершенстве - (байт код из bcompile -> php код), но сойдет и (байт код из bcompile -> assembler)

Comment: влезть в этап выполнения - только с помощью дебаггера или скомпилировать php самому, поставив хуки в нужных местах

Comment: тоже возникла такая идея(просто влезть в процесс), но может есть и другие способы?

P.S да, оп-коды, конечно же

Comment: @0xFFh апдейт ответа

Comment: vld - хорошая вещь, но мне, все-таки нужно произвести декомпиляцию на уровне байт-кода, который получается на выходе  из bcompiler_write_file.
Сейчас не уверен, что vld в этом может помочь, хотя может просто читатл невнимательно.

Comment: Может и получится. Что ж, и на этом спасибо

Comment: В общем, если интересно, положение дел таково(надеюсь, скажу что-то новое): bcompiler генерит zend`овские опкоды из php-кода, то же самое производит и vld.  Следовательно, подавать на вход vld результат работы bcompiler`а равносильно тому, что xor`ить A дважды на B. Отсюда возникла более лояльная потребность: как бы можно было распарсить результат bcompiler`а и привести его к виду vld?